# What's easiest way to start a spring project?

Tags: spring, eclipse, ide

The STS tool is not working in Eclipse Neon and I'm wondering what's the easiest way to start a spring project in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using spring's initializer site https://start.spring.io/ ?
The basic template created there can be imported as an existing project in most IDEs.